# Neural Network Prediction regression task, output is a multiple factor of input with same peaks

Tags: python, neural-network, rnn, lstm

When I missed some details please point this out. I made a simple sequential LSTM model for regression. The model loss is 3.2145e-06. The data is scaled between 0 and 1. I tried different variations of layers etc but the same happend, the simpliest model I used is the following one:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,1))
model.add(LSTM(1,activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae','mse']) 
history=model.fit(train,train, epochs=10, batch_size=78, shuffle=False)

predicted=model.predict(test)
```

My train data looks like:

[image]

When I compare the test and predicted, predicted looks likes being many times smaller than the test data and showing the exact peak values. In my case I expect the values to be small because I trained with totally different data (kind of anomaly regression), what is surprising are the peak values being identical. testdata plot above and predicted below. So my question why this with the peaks are happening and how can I make the network not be able to detect the peaks and predict as trained ?

[image: testdata]

[image: predicted]

Edit: 
After using MAE as loss function and 500 epochs training I reached 0.0180 loss. The prediction looks like mirrored of the mse prediction (see below). After 2000 epochs I reached a minium of 0.0030 and th

[image]

After 2000 epochs I reached a minium of 0.0030 and the prediction looks like this: [image]

Edit: my data is on supposed to work with LSTM, I needed an other model.

Comment: are you training with MSE?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan yes it is a regression problem, I forgot to include that. I did not use any other loss function. Do you have anything to suggest ?

Comment: The problem with MSE is that when delta's are less than 1 they vanish due to taking the square. Try using MAE (mean absolute error) instead.

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan thanks for the hint, I tried it out please see the results in my edit. I try to reach that the model only predicts the values range of train data. Now I am thinking maybe my train data is not good enough or what could it be ?

Comment: What optimizer are you using? What are the parameters of the optimizer? Have you tried increasing the hidden size of the LSTM (more than 16)?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan sorry that was missed out as well. I used adam and rmsprop but same results. I increased the hidden size of lstm to much more (128) but my problem was still the same as with using mse as loss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79673/discussion-between-annstudent93-and-armen-aghajanyan).

Comment: Try to use leaky-relu.

Comment: Try to use closure, `def my_relu(alpha):
    def my_leaky_relu(z):
        return tf.nn.leaky_relu(z, alpha)
    return my_leaky_relu`

Comment: @Media I am using Keras but could do it right now, still the same problems with the prediction of the peaks

Comment: What is the accuracy?

Comment: also try to manipulate alpha

Comment: @Media I played with alpha  between 0.001 and 0.1, the loss is really less (2.e-05), I get the same peaks in the prediction as in the test data, which makes it look like a prediction divided just by a factor.

Comment: Are you normalising the output?

Comment: @Media No I am not doing this

Comment: So try to do it :)